# What happened if android device has no bluetooth support when beacon runs

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, beacon, estimote

I am running beacon in my Application class like this :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000, 25000);
        beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {

            }
        });
        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {

                beaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region("rid", null, null, null));
            }
        });

    }
```

It's running on my device correctly, but in emulator it crashes. Because emulator does not have bluetooth support. So my question is IF real device does not have bluetooth what will happen? If it will crash how can I prevent it? And is it possible that android device higher than 4.3 does't have bluetooth?

```
 E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference
                                                               at com.estimote.sdk.service.internal.JellyBeanBluetoothAdapter.start(JellyBeanBluetoothAdapter.java:43)
                                                               at com.estimote.sdk.service.internal.CycleBluetoothScanner.start(CycleBluetoothScanner.java:64)
                                                               at com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService.startScanning(BeaconService.java:336)
                                                               at com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService.startMonitoring(BeaconService.java:286)
                                                               at com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService.access$300(BeaconService.java:69)
                                                               at com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService$IncomingHandler$1.run(BeaconService.java:440)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: you need to check the Bluetooth permission before executing bacon code, when the device has Bluetooth it will run else show than a message that device is not supported.

Comment: What's the exception you got? Post the logcat.

Comment: you should not have to worry regarding this issue. because there are rare devices because i have not listen even any one device that not have a bluetooth device.

Comment: @AndroidGeek thank you

Comment: @Henry I added  the exception from emulator

Comment: You can add <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/> and <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/> to AndroidManifest to prevent install your app on devices wothout bluetoth

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    //Bluetooth is not supported
} else{
    //Bluetooth is supported
}
```

Also Don't forget to add Bluetooth permission in manifest.